# How do I enable a mode, when another mode runs?

Tags: hooks, major-mode, minor-mode, tern

All I want to do is enable `tern-mode`, when I enter `js-mode`.  I know that a hook called `js-mode` is run when I open a javascript file but for some reason `tern-mode` is not enabled.  In my init.el file I have:

`(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () ('tern-mode)))`

I also tried:

`(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))`

as well as both of those with `js-mode-hook` (This was mostly for fun though because it makes no difference, see the comments)

I have also tried:

`(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'tern-mode)`

And this does't work.  However, `tern-mode` does not get enabled when I enter `js2-mode`.  To enable it, each time I have to press `M-x tern-mode`, then it works.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to enable a minor mode named `tern-mode` when entering the major mode named `js-mode`, you can use `(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'tern-mode)`, you usually don't have to wrap `tern-mode` unless you have very old version of Emacs or some other special reason.  `js2-mode` and `js-mode` is different thing, figure which you're using. Tern's doc already says how to use it, see http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs

Comment: Reading the documentation for `js2-mode` says: `In addition to any hooks its parent mode `js-mode' might have run,                                                                                         
 15 this mode runs the hook `js2-mode-hook', as the final step                                                                                                 
 16 during initialization. `

I have the newest (24.5) version of emacs and have tried your suggestions and it does not work.

Comment: Startec: `(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'tern-mode)` works fine for me (aside from erroring out because I don't have `tern` installed; but the minor mode is enabled as expected).

Comment: @phils thanks for trying to help me out. I looked at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258066/tern-auto-complete-wont-start-automatically

As it seemed closely related but I couldn't find anything useful.

I can't figure out what it is. Those are single quotes right?

Comment: Yes, plain ascii apostrophes. You can alternatively write `(add-hook (quote js-mode-hook) (quote tern-mode))` if you wish to eliminate all doubt about the punctuation marks. In either case, `C-h v js-mode-hook RET` should report the value as `(tern-mode)` -- or perhaps some longer list of which `tern-mode` is a member, at any rate. Once you're in `js2-mode`, check whether `Tern` is displayed in the mode line; or type `C-h m` and see whether `Tern` is listed amongst the minor modes.

Comment: Hm, I have been using ascii apostrophes but when typing `C-h m`, tern mode is not listed among the minor modes until I explicitly call it with `M-x tern-mode`.

What I get with `C-h v js-mode-hook RET` is `Its value is (skewer-mode ac-js2-mode ac-js2-setup-auto-complete-mode) ` . `tern mode` is not in that list

Comment: correction: 
What I get with `C-h v js-mode-hook RET` is `Its value is (tern-mode skewer-mode ac-js2-mode ac-js2-setup-auto-complete-mode) ` . but it still does not immediately open.

Comment: @Startec: note that only recent versions of js2-mode derive from js-mode.  So if the user has an earlier version it might not run `js-mode-hook`.  In any case I suspect the `*Messages*` might contain some hint.

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately the only message in the messages buffer at all is only about the snippets. I.e. `[yas] Loading compiled snippets from /home/optonox/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150927.1716/snippets/js-mode`  Is the only line with "`js`" in it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer here is:

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'tern-mode)
```

This line of code is in my emacs config and works fine. When I open a `.js` file, `tern-mode` is enabled.

If that doesn't work, there are other things to debug, such as what package manager you're using, which files you're opening, whether tern has any [prerequirements](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs) you're not fulfilling (like a server available in `bin/tern` ?), etc.