# How to turn on a minor mode in my init file?

Tags: init-file, minor-mode

I want to add `global-semantic-idle-summary-mode` in my .emacs file instead of calling everytime it by using M-x.
I tried with `(setq ...)` but it doesn't work. What's the right way?

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17014/105

Comment: Possible duplicate of [global-auto-revert-mode doesn't seem to work?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/global-auto-revert-mode-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Voting as duplicate. If not a duplicate, the proposed duplicate contains the `.emacs` syntax that should allow for enabling a global minor mode. If that doesn't work edit the question to include what was attempted (but did not work) from the suggestions in it.

Answer (score 4):

It is a minor-mode which can be enabled with:  `(global-semantic-idle-summary-mode 1)`

The doc-string states:  "*Toggle Global Semantic Idle Summary mode.  With ARG, turn Global Semantic Idle Summary mode on if ARG is positive, off otherwise.  When this minor mode is enabled, 'semantic-idle-summary-mode' is turned on in every Semantic-supported buffer.*"

In general, a user may test for whether a minor-mode is active by inspecting the variable containing the same -- e.g., `M-x describe-variable RET semantic-idle-summary-mode RET`  Unless the variable has been specifically defined beforehand, it will not exist until the minor-mode has been activated.

Comment: And `describe-variable` is bound to `C-h v`.